# Processing Large Files into Variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I wrote an upload tool that users can upload thousands of rows that need to be processed on our end. The flow diagram is the following :

1. Upload
2. Read PHP temp file and build Multi Dimensional Nested Array

   2.a  Pure array Array[key][key2][key3] = row[]  (with up to 10 properties)

   OR

   2.b  Current Solution Serialize the data Array[key][key2][key3] = json_encode(row[])
3. Compare the uploaded data with our data on MySQL
4. Update or insert.

**Few notes** 
I need to make a nested array to go through the data by chunks , I cannot query our database 150,000 times. I aggregate the uploaded data by certain categories and then query the DB.

I have already tried using a tmp file with a blank nested array. 
Also Ordering the File was crossed out as it would take the same amount of processing.

The following is a memory test of a File that had 150,000 Rows of data.
I first try to load it all in memory .
Then I try to serialize it at the cost of process time.

Then I tried HHVM .

```
    /*
              Line Number   Memory In MB

    mem usage at # 10000 -     103.6

    */


    php memtest.php
    mem usage 0.6
    mem usage at # 0 - 0.7  //Memory used in MB get_memory_usage()
    mem usage at # 10000 -  103.6
    mem usage at # 20000 -  206.2
    mem usage at # 30000 -  308.7
    mem usage at # 40000 -  411.1
    mem usage at # 50000 -  513.4
    mem usage at # 60000 -  615.7
    mem usage at # 70000 -  718.1
    mem usage at # 80000 -  820.4
    mem usage at # 90000 -  922.5
    mem usage at # 100000 - 1024.6
    mem usage at # 110000 - 1126.7
    mem usage at # 120000 - 1228.7
    mem usage at # 130000 - 1330.9
    mem usage at # 140000 - 1434.1
    mem usage at # 150000 - 1537.2
    19.02784705162

    serialize
    mem usage 0.7
    mem usage at # 0 - 0.7
    mem usage at # 10000 -  8.3
    mem usage at # 20000 -  15.8
    mem usage at # 30000 -  23.2
    mem usage at # 40000 -  30.5
    mem usage at # 50000 -  37.7
    mem usage at # 60000 -  44.8
    mem usage at # 70000 -  51.9
    mem usage at # 80000 -  59
    mem usage at # 90000 -  65.9
    mem usage at # 100000 - 73
    mem usage at # 110000 - 80
    mem usage at # 120000 - 87
    mem usage at # 130000 - 94.1
    mem usage at # 140000 - 101.9
    mem usage at # 150000 - 109.7
    24.386758089066

    hhvm memtest.php 
    mem usage 2  
    mem usage at # 0 - 2
    mem usage at # 10000 -  28
    mem usage at # 20000 -  56
    mem usage at # 30000 -  82
    mem usage at # 40000 -  108
    mem usage at # 50000 -  136
    mem usage at # 60000 -  162
    mem usage at # 70000 -  190
    mem usage at # 80000 -  216
    mem usage at # 90000 -  244
    mem usage at # 100000 - 270
    mem usage at # 110000 - 296
    mem usage at # 120000 - 324
    mem usage at # 130000 - 350
    mem usage at # 140000 - 378
    mem usage at # 150000 - 406
    4.0886609554291

    serialize
    mem usage 422      (422-406=16m)
    mem usage at # 0 - 422      // 16
    mem usage at # 10000 - 430  // 28
    mem usage at # 20000 - 438  // 36
    mem usage at # 30000 - 446  // 44
    mem usage at # 40000 - 452  // 50
    mem usage at # 50000 - 460  // 58
    mem usage at # 60000 - 468  // 66
    mem usage at # 70000 - 476  // 74
    mem usage at # 80000 - 484  // 82
    mem usage at # 90000 - 492  // 90
    mem usage at # 100000 - 498 // 96
    mem usage at # 110000 - 506 // 104
    mem usage at # 120000 - 514 // 112
    mem usage at # 130000 - 522 // 120
    mem usage at # 140000 - 530 // 128
    mem usage at # 150000 - 538 // 136

    14.125330924988
```

My question is what is the optimal way to deal with large data sets in PHP? 
Are there more optimal way of storing data in variables?

Comment: "optimal way"? Load as little into memory as is possible, process, clear memory, repeat. "as little as possible" is entirely dependent on the nature of your data and how you need to process it. There is no "magic bullet". You need to elaborate on the exact structure of your input and the processing that needs to be done to it before anyone can even begin to suggest what you can do to address the memory usage of your program.

Comment: Load the file into a database table and do your processing with sql.

Comment: Yes @DanBracuk We are actually thinking of doing that with a temporary table or staging table.